# My query didn't work

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I tried many time to get the right result but I'm always fail. I can't find what's wrong in my codes. I want also to distinct the create_time and close_time, so that the date will not repeat.Please help me.

This is the sample output that I need:

```
ID         NAME      CREATE_TIME     CREATEDCOUNT    CLOSE_TIME   CLOSEDCOUNT     

1          POS        01-JAN-14           1           01-JAN-14      1
2          EMAIL      02-JAN-14           10          02-JAN-14     10
```

THIS IS MY QUERY:

```
SELECT t.create_time, t.queue_id, q.name
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
LEFT JOIN APP_ACOUNT.OTRS_QUEUE q
ON t.queue_id = q.id
WHERE t.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -7 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY trunc(t.create_time), t.queue_id, q.name
ORDER BY trunc(t.create_time), t_id, q.name;
```

THE TABLE SCHEMA FOR APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET (some data)

```
 ID TITLE                         QUEUE_ID ... .... .... .... ....  ....  ....        CREATE_TIME   .... .... CLOSE_TIME ..... ..... 

 39 Cannot access the Zimbra Email 11      5     1     3   2  hcph  hcph  POS-generic 15-OCT-13       5    \N  15-OCT-13 5    Office 
 40 Slow WIFI Connection           21      5     1     3   2  hcph  hcph  POS-generic 15-OCT-13       5    \N  15-OCT-13 5    Office 
 41 Change phone number in IDM      7      5     1     3   2  hcph  hcph  hcphuser   15-OCT-13       5    \N 15-OCT-13  5    Office
```

TABLE SCHEMA FOR APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_QUEUE (SOME DATA)

```
 ID      NAME
 58 Facilities and Procurement::Office Furniture Request
 59 Facilities and Procurement::Supplies Request ��� Marketing & Sales
 60 Facilities and Procurement::Supplies Request ��� Office Supplies
 2  Raw
 66 Procurement::Supplies Request - Office Supplies
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @San i already mention above

Comment: why are you using `trunc`

Comment: give table schema and some sample data tooo

Comment: Please do mention the tables involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this query:

```
SELECT t.queue_id, 
       q.name,  
       trunc(t.create_time), 
       count(t.create_time) createcount,  
       trunc(t.close_time), 
       count(t.close_time) closedcount, 
  FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET t
       LEFT JOIN APP_ACOUNT.OTRS_QUEUE q
       ON t.queue_id = q.id
 WHERE t.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -7 AND SYSDATE
 GROUP BY trunc(t.create_time), t.queue_id, q.name, trunc(t.close_time);
```

If this doesn't solves your problem then give the details of both tables and some sample data because I created this query on various assumptions.

Comment: I receive an error -- ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: @user3172075 - this query copies your original in having two schema names; `APP_ACCOUNT` and `APP_ACOUNT` (with one `C`). Presumably that's a mistake in your original code. That should have been pretty obvious from the error message, surely.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't notice. the query is now running correctly. I have a question. I have another query similar in the question but when I run it the create_time and close_time have a duplicate. What's wrong?

Comment: @user3172075 : Probably you are using wrong column list in the group by clause.

Comment: how come? here's my query: SELECT trunc(create_time), COUNT(*) CreatedCount, trunc(close_time), COUNT(*) CloseCount
FROM APP_ACCOUNT.OTRS_TICKET
WHERE CREATE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -7 AND SYSDATE
AND CLOSE_TIME BETWEEN SYSDATE -7 AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY trunc(create_time), trunc(close_time)
ORDER BY trunc(create_time), trunc(close_time);

Comment: The date is duplicate like 01/01/14 01/01/14 instead 01/01/14 only

Comment: If you are telling that you are getting two dates in a row, its because you are selecting two dates actually, ie trunc(create_time) and trunc(close_time), if you want to keep only one, then select which ever you need in your select list.

Comment: Ok. I see, so its not possible to combine the two table? Now, its clear to me